# Model for application route in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-controllers

I have the following code where I am trying to set the model for `ApplicationRoute` but it doesn't seem to work. I have a few doubts regarding the Ember code. Firstly, Can I set a model for application route? Secondly, if the model for the route has fields named count and fileName, do I need to declare these fields in the controller also. It looks like if I do so, the value in the controller takes precedence over the model value. Also can I do something like `this.set('total',5)` in the `setupController` even though total isn't defined anywhere.

```
App.ApplicationRoute=Ember.Route.extend({
model:function(){
    console.log('model called');
    return {count:3,fileName:'Doc1'};
},
setupController:function(){
    console.log(this.get('model').fileName);
    this.set('count',this.get('model.count')); //Do I manually need to do this?
    this.set('fileName',this.get('model.fileName')); //Do I manually need to do this?
}
});
App.ApplicationController=Ember.Controller.extend({
    count:0,//Is this necessary?? Can I directly set the property with declaring it like this
    fileName:''
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
App.ApplicationController=Ember.Controller.extend({
    count: function(){
       return this.get('model').get('count');
    }.property('model.count')
});
```

So anytime `model.count` changes, the propery would get updated automatically.

And yep, you can set the model directly on the route. When you do `this.set('total', 5)` in the controller, you only set that property on the controller and not the model. In order to update the model, you would need to do:

```
var model = this.get('model');
model.set('total', 5);
```

Lastly, your `setupController` code isn't correct. Here is the sample method found on the Ember docs ([located here](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/representing-a-single-model-with-objectcontroller/)):

```
App.SongRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, song) {
    controller.set('model', song);
  }
});
```

Comment: So what you are suggesting is that I should use computed properties for everything thats in the model? I actually I found out if just extend my controller from ObjectController rather than just Controller, the properties from model are automatically available in the controller